# Blender Won't Stop Rendering Sequencer

Tags: rendering, 3d-view, eevee-render-engine, video-sequence-editor

What the title says

I tried unchecking compositing and sequencer in Output Properties --> Post Processing. I removed all clips from the sequence editor. I removed all sequence editor windows. But it keeps rendering the video sequencer. I'm just trying to render PNG's
[image]

I'm using 2.92

What else can I try?

Comment: What makes you think it’s rendering the sequencer?

Comment: Because it's rendering an animation from an old video that was in the sequencer. What I have in the viewport is different now.

Comment: if you removed all clips from the sequencer, that is crazy. The contrapositive is true as well.

Comment: Maybe, you can try to clear the cache. Or, you can add a new movie strip to the sequencer and see if it is rendering this one (or still the old one). If the new one, then try to delete this strip and see what's happening

Comment: sounds weird...can you upload your blend file so we can check it out?

Comment: Oh...My...God. Storytime. I wanted to upload the file. It was toio big. I tried seeing if deleting some assets could make it smaller. It didn't. I realized that rendering the new image wouldn't show the deleted assets. Only the new modifier on my main object wasn't showing in the render view...BECAUSE I ACCIDENTALLY CLICKED OFF THE RENDER BUTTON ON THE MODIFIER.